# How can I change the font of my ListView items?

Tags: java, android, sql, listview, fonts

I have the problem that i would like to create an custom design for my list view but I don't know how to do. I use a sql database which is in my list view. haha sorry I dont't know how to say this...because im german..so by the way sorry for my englsih. here is my code:

```
private void populateListViewFromDB() {
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);


    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
            {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME, DBAdapter.KEY_STUDENTNUM, DBAdapter.KEY_FAVCOLOUR, DBAdapter.KEY_STUDENTNUM};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
            {R.id.item_name,     R.id.item_icon,           R.id.item_favcolour,     R.id.item_studentnum};


    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,       
                    R.layout.item_layout,   
                    cursor,                 
                    fromFieldNames,         
                    toViewIDs               
                    );

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFromDB);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

Thank you for helping!:)

Comment: you have to create a custom adapter to do so..

Comment: but I already using an adapter. Could this work?

Comment: 1) You can set any custom font you want. 2) But you should only do that when it is really necessary. Users can pick any custom font they want in the settings of their device. if you force some other font on them you are just going to annoy the ones that would like to have a custom one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks the minimum effort in using a search engine. There's **a ton** of tutorials demonstrating the use of custom items

Comment: yes but could this word with more than one adapter?

Comment: open res/layout/item_layout.xml. Change the font there. So it will be changed.

Comment: @JoeRichard I would like to use an ttf font;)

Comment: Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf"); 
   txtyour.setTypeface(type);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Here is a detailed explanation of the issue.

http://javatechig.com/android/using-external-fonts-in-android-view

Basically for you, since it's in a listview I recommend that you create the custom textview. It's important to place you font files in the assets folder.

Comment: @360Productions,Glad to help you..