# Cant change listview font in listactivity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Im very new in android programming, and my task is to load up the items in my shared preference to a listview, and i just want to change the design of my listview, like changing its font color, font size and etc.. I have tried this solution but it doesn't work, please tell me where I did wrong. Thanks..
heres my code in loading the listview in a listactivity

```
Map<String,?> datakeys = datapref.getAll();
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : datakeys.entrySet()){
        Log.d("values123",entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());    
        lvlist.add(entry.getValue().toString());}
    lvadapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mytextview , R.id.text1, lvlist);
    //lvadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, lvlist);
    setListAdapter(lvadapter);
```

heres the mytextview xml..

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:id="@+id/text1"  
            android:paddingTop="2dip" 
            android:paddingBottom="3dip" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
```

and my listview xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:background="#b6fcd5" >

</ListView>
```

here's the screenshots
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by *it doesn't work* ? Are you getting any error?

Comment: I didn't see any changes in my listview

Comment: Attach the screen shot

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121219/how-can-i-change-the-font-of-my-listview-items/26121491#26121491

Comment: change the ArrayAdpter line @AyamSakata and also change the id of `TextView`

Comment: just use customAdapter and you can do any style with your textview you want :)

Comment: @AyamSakata :  why are you afraid of giving you own id for list as android:id="@+id/list" rather than as android:id="@android:id/list" please have a look on my answer too ...

Answer (score 0):

You need other constructor of `ArrayAdapter`  :

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

so Change this line to :

```
lvadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mytextview, lvlist);
```

To :

```
lvadapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mytextview , R.id.text1, lvlist);
```

And `mytextview xml` :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/text1"  
        android:paddingTop="2dip" 
        android:paddingBottom="3dip" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
```

If this doesn't work , then Go with `Custom Adapter`

Comment: I did what you suggested but it still looks like the on the screenshot.. nothing changed

Comment: Changed the Adapter ?? and mytextview.xml too??

Comment: Then better to go with Custom Adapter

Comment: I edited my question according to your suggestions, I do not really know why it still do not work..

Answer (score 0):

one more approach: have a look

```
 String [] yourStringarrayorlist= {"Lionssss","Cats", "yeaaahhh :)"};

        ListView listView =new ListView(
                    getApplicationContext()); 
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourStringarrayorlist) {
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                      // if you want to change any specific items color
                        int textColor = textView.getText().toString().equals("Cats") ? R.color.any : android.R.color.black;
                        textView.setTextColor(VideoviewActivity.this.getResources().getColor(textColor));

                       //If you want to change the text color of all use below code
                       // textView.setTextColor(VideoviewActivity.this.getResources().getColor( R.color.any));


                        return textView;
                    }
                });
    layoutrela.addView(listView);
```

---

You can change the textcolor easily. However for just a check i've created ListView through code and added to the layout :) but it works like awesome.. 
Inspired by : [How to change text color of simple list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563698/how-to-change-text-color-of-simple-list-item)
not a new answer so i would not expect any vote or so.