# Customise inbuilt ListView in ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-styles, listactivity

I want to customise the inbuilt list within a `ListActivity`. I would rather do it in my resources, rather than dynamically.

I've been working and searching this and having difficulty solving it.
There is this question [Cant change listview font in listactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418860/cant-change-listview-font-in-listactivity), but there is no elegant answer.

I have a listview:

```
<ListView
    style="@style/ListView"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

With style resource:

```
<style name="ListView">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
     ...
</style>
```

The styles works for other elements. It's only when I use `android:id="@android:id/list"`. The default settings for the text overrides any customised settings.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will be using adapter for sure, so supply your custom item layout in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by doing this.

Create listview_row.xml in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#00ffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your code implement array adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>(this, 
            R.layout.listview_row, R.id.textList, yourListValue);
setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```