# How to use custom font in custom BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android

I am creating an Android app using Android Studio.
I have listview in an activity that is using a custom SimpleAdapter.
I need to use a custom font in the custom adapter but when I try it does not work.
No errors only no font is being used. The font path works fine when used directly in an activity.

When I log out the fonter created I get this:

```
E/====﹕ FONT: android.graphics.Typeface@4c5dfbc0
```

This is my custom adapter code:

```
package com.myapp.app.utilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.fieldly41.app.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SimpleIconAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results;

    //private Context context;

    Typeface font;

    public SimpleIconAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {

        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

        this.results = data;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = view;

        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon, null);

        }

        if(results.get(position) != null ) {

            Typeface fonter = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/ss-symbolicons-line.ttf");

            TextView top_label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.top_label);
            TextView icon_label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView bottom_label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottom_label);

            icon_label.setText("");
            icon_label.setTypeface(fonter);

            if (results.get(position).get("locked").equals("false")) {

                icon_label.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            } else {

                icon_label.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            }

            top_label.setText(results.get(position).get("title"));
            bottom_label.setText(results.get(position).get("created_at"));

        }

        return v;

    }

}
```

Comment: don't get font from view get it from context it will work 
Like Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fontname.ttf");

Comment: Instead of set your custom font in adapter create your custom TextView with font.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121219/how-can-i-change-the-font-of-my-listview-items/26121491#26121491

Answer (score 1):

Your implementations is near to ok.

But the big problem is you are creating a `TypeFace` instance in `getView()` method which is very resource hungry.

Because `getView()` method calls repeatedly N numbers of time whenever you scroll the list.

And loading resource from assets extensively is bad practice, it may cause `OutOfMemoryError` any time.

So my recommendation is create common object and use in getView().

```
public SimpleIconAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {

        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ss-symbolicons-line.ttf");
        this.results = data;


    }
```

In getView() remove this Line

```
Typeface fonter = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/ss-symbolicons-line.ttf");
```

And use "font" object instead fonter

```
icon_label.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: I tried this before too, but it did not use the font.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I did.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The font is not being used. I only see the cymbol, not the font.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Since it's a listview, I would suggest you to create a custom textview and take it inside the row layout xml.

**Note:** It's important that you place required font files in the `assets` folder.

Create Custom TextView with your custom font.

**CustomTextView.java**

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFont();
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFont();
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setFont();
    }

    private void setFont() {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/ss-symbolicons-line.ttf");
        setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

Try define Custom TextView instead of simple TextView which you would like to shown your custom font.

**list_item_icon.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <yourpackagename.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Care about Custom TextView declaration and initialization and try to use [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) concept when you use Custom adapter.

```
public class SimpleIconAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results;

    public SimpleIconAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.results = data;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon, null);
            holder.top_label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.top_label);
            holder.icon_label = (CustomTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.bottom_label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_label);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.icon_label.setText("");

        if (results.get(position).get("locked").equals("false")) {
            holder.icon_label.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            holder.icon_label.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        holder.top_label.setText(results.get(position).get("title"));
        holder.bottom_label.setText(results.get(position).get("created_at"));

        return view;

    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView top_label;
        CustomTextView icon_label;
        TextView bottom_label;
    }

}
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and I still do not get the font to be used/work. Sorry.

Comment: Once again, don't suggest solution by dumping whole code, instead just write down pin points! Let them do R&D them self.

Comment: @PareshMayani,Now is it okay or not ?

Comment: @PareshMayani,do you have any problem with my code or shall i done something wrong in my code now i realize you very personal with my ans.