# How to display data in custom font in listview in listadapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fonts

I have a code here, I want to change font in listview and display it,in listadapter. however, it doesn't help but only show a default number rather than real data. Is this the correct way of change font of my data?

```
       ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity3.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item3, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE, TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.username,R.id.p_title, R.id.approval }){

                @Override
                public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                    View v = convertView;
                    if(v== null){
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v=vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item3, null);
                    }
                    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
                    Typeface custom_fontG = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                              "fonts/orange juice 2.0.ttf");
                              tv.setTypeface(custom_fontG); 


                    TextView tv2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.p_title);
                    Typeface custom_fontH = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                              "fonts/orange juice 2.0.ttf");
                              tv2.setTypeface(custom_fontH); 

                    TextView tv3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.approval);
                                Typeface custom_fontI = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                          "fonts/orange juice 2.0.ttf");
                                          tv3.setTypeface(custom_fontI);
                    return v;
                }
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505109/how-to-use-custom-font-in-custom-baseadapter/26505473#26505473

Comment: Actually your Question Title is not related to your Question description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this may help you,

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity3.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item3, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE, TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.username,R.id.p_title, R.id.approval }){

                @Override
                public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                    View v = convertView;
                    if(v== null){
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v=vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item3, null);
                    }

                    HashMap<String,String> value = productsList.get(pos);

                    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
                    Typeface custom_fontG = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                              "fonts/orange juice 2.0.ttf");
                              tv.setTypeface(custom_fontG); 
                    tv.setText(value.get(//put key to get value from hashmap)); 


                    TextView tv2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.p_title);
                    Typeface custom_fontH = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                              "fonts/orange juice 2.0.ttf");
                              tv2.setTypeface(custom_fontH); 
                    tv2.setText(value.get(//put key to get value from hashmap)); 

                    TextView tv3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.approval);
                                Typeface custom_fontI = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                          "fonts/orange juice 2.0.ttf");
                                          tv3.setTypeface(custom_fontI);
                    tv3.setText(value.get(//put key to get value from hashmap)); 
                    return v;
                }
```

Comment: Hi, @moradiya akash, I don't really understand this line tv2.setText(productsList.get(position).get("")); , what is the position? Where sould I declare it?

Comment: can you tell me data type of productsList?

Comment: I declare as this   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;  @Moradiya Akash

Comment: you have to put there key of hashmap

Comment: just like TAG_DESCRIPTION you have used

Comment: Yup, it has error, I put in tag and it has error in value there.

Comment: It has no error in the end, but when I run the apps, it crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Set text to your `TextView` like

```
tv.setText(fetch data from arrayList as per Position); 

tv.setText(""+pos);
```

do the same for other `TextViews`

Comment: Hi, I'm rookie in android, can you tell me how to fetch data from arraylist as per position?

Comment: @M D, I make it run, but unfortunately, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

rename your font file name

```
Typeface custom_fontG = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                          "fonts/orange juice 2.0.ttf");
```

to `Typeface custom_fontG = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                              "fonts/orange_juice_2.0.ttf");`

use `_` where space is there