# how to specify the font file in the settings instead of code?

Tags: android, android-typeface

I'm trying to decorate my application fonts. I get to do it from code. but do not know how to do it in the settings. in the code I do so

```
public class Fonts {
    public static Typeface getHeaderFont(Context context){
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "header_levelI.ttf");
    }
    public static Typeface getSubHeaderFont(Context context){
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "header_levelII.ttf");
    }
}
```

and

```
Typeface type= Fonts.getHeaderFont(getActivity());
        TextView header = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cassaName);
        header.setTypeface(type);
```

settings android studio only standard fonts. How do I specify fonts in the file not to write extra code?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not supported for now...

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505109/how-to-use-custom-font-in-custom-baseadapter/26505473#26505473

Comment: @HareshChhelana is correct. Given link solves the problem, +1 & raised your comment as an important flag

Comment: @RIT,you can appreciate by given upvote linked ans and thanks.

Comment: @PavelPetrashov,check my ans.

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom TextView with your custom font.

**Note:** It's important that you place required font files in the assets/fonts directory.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFont();
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFont();
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setFont();
    }

    private void setFont() {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/ss-symbolicons-line.ttf");
        setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
}
```