# Custom font not working in fragment - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fonts

I have added a custom font into the `assets` folder.

My hierarchy looks like this,

[image: Android project hierarchy]

I have a fragment that I am trying to set the font in. This is my code for setting the font within the fragment,

```
TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
        "myfont.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

This is done within the `onCreateView()` method.

When I run this code I get this **LogCat** error,

```
void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
```

**Fragment onCreateView()**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover, container, false);

    TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
            "myfont.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);

    return rootView;
}
```

Why can't the fragment find the font?

Comment: show your fragment code.

Comment: This not a duplicate. I have followed the steps of the suppose duplicate and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: The logcat error is shown

Comment: @GaryJohnson Might be `txt=null`

Comment: you do this in the fragment's onCreate right? 

try this

`Typeface localTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(((Activity) rootView.getContext()).getAssets(), "Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf");`

Where rootView is your inflated view

Comment: @GaryJohnson .. first debug your app and see is "font" object is null or not...you can also do something like this... if(font!=null){txt.setTypeface(font);} and see is app crash with same exception

Comment: or you can replace "getActivity()" with "<ACTIVITY-NAME.this>" and check

Comment: @AbhishekVasisht I tried that method and still received the same error.

Comment: @AngadTiwari I tried ` if(font!=null){txt.setTypeface(font);}` and the app still crashes with the same error.

Comment: As suggested debug and step through the code.

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505109/how-to-use-custom-font-in-custom-baseadapter

Comment: I'm not sure how this changes things, but people advice to put all fonts in a "fonts" folder in the assets folder

Comment: The problem is this line `Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "myfont.ttf");`. It can't find the font. It is returning null.

Comment: @GaryJohnson ..do one more thing ' if(font!=null || txt!=null){txt.setTypeface(font);}' and check